How to get all AMM infos that related with Raydium Liquidity V4?
I am currently working on a project to execute swap trades on Raydium Liquidity V4. In order to complete these trades, I need to collect the account keys of all AMMs associated with Raydium Liquidity V4. Each AMM has its own unique account key that is required for the trade.
Below you can find the trade with instructions for Raydium Liquidity V4. You will need the account keys for each AMM to trade.
https://solscan.io/tx/567FXFnQhpa8573sW8DHGN6XuNshhCFhvr6aVWgRZ71Vk2v6WnbbYtYiGqeC8RezzWzg7tGorFoZ3DioZf6ZroB5
I would greatly appreciate any help in obtaining this information. Thanks for your help!
Thanks
